# Displaying a standard icon and text in QLabel

Tags: pyqt, qlabel

I want to display a standard warning icon along with some description text in `QLabel` in *pyqt*. `Qlabel` doesn't have `setIcon` function. So how could I do that?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 23):

`QLabel` doesn't have a `setIcon` method, but it has [`setPixmap`](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qlabel.html#setPixmap). But if you use that to set a [`QPixmap`](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qpixmap.html) it overrides your text. but there are a few possibilities to achieve what you want:

- use the html-capabilities of the `QLabel` to display text+image
- use two labels, one with the text and one with the image
- paint the component yourself

Comment: Would you mind adding an example showing how to "use the html-capabilities of the QLabel to display text+image"?

Comment: That means just add an `<img>` tag pointing to the image (`QLabel("<html><img src='/path/to/my_image.png'></html>")`) or image [resource](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/resources.html) defined in your `.qrc` (`QLabel("<html><img src=':/my_image.png'></html>")`)

Comment: As displaying both a pixmap and text in the same `QLabel` is trivially feasible (if cumbersome) via the [`<img>` hack above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10533838/displaying-a-standard-icon-and-text-in-qlabel#comment37584016_10574811), it's disappointing (if unsurprising) that `QLabel` supports no such functionality out-of-the-box. Why were `setPixmap()` and `setText()` forced to be mutually exclusive, when the two could have been made to simplistically cooperate in the obvious way (e.g., by prepending or appending text with an `<img>`-wrapped pixmap in rich text mode)?

Answer (score 6):

I know I'm a bit late to the party, but here's my solution to this problem:

```python
import qtawesome as qta
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class IconLabel(QWidget):

    IconSize = QSize(16, 16)
    HorizontalSpacing = 2

    def __init__(self, qta_id, text, final_stretch=True):
        super(QWidget, self).__init__()

        layout = QHBoxLayout()
        layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.setLayout(layout)

        icon = QLabel()
        icon.setPixmap(qta.icon(qta_id).pixmap(self.IconSize))

        layout.addWidget(icon)
        layout.addSpacing(self.HorizontalSpacing)
        layout.addWidget(QLabel(text))

        if final_stretch:
            layout.addStretch()
```

I am using [`QtAwesome`](https://pypi.org/project/QtAwesome/) to get the desired icon.

Now you can easily insert the icon label into your own PyQt5 layout. Example.

```python
mylayout.addWidget(IconLabel("fa.scissors", "Slicer Limit:"))
```

What it looks like:

[image]

Note that I included an option `final_stretch`. In a vertical layout, you'll want to keep `final_stretch = True` for proper left-alignment (see image avove). In a horizontal layout (i.e., when placing multiple `IconLabels` next to each other in the same row), however, you'll probably want to set `final_stretch = False` in order to save space.

Answer (score -1):

**Try this, I hope this will work fine**`install qtawesome using the following command:

> pip install qtawesome

you can use any kind of icon from qtawesome.

`

```
import qtawesome as qta

icon = qta.icon("fa.lock",color='blue')
self.ssl_label.setPixmap(icon.pixmap(QSize(16,16)))
```